al crear un componete hijo desde un metodo en vue 2 no se envian los props
Tengo un metodo que crea un componente de vue 2 que al momento de enviar el props no lo toma el componente hijo
childComponent() {
      const childComponent = new Vue({
        extends: CallClient,
        props: {
          message: '¡Hola desde el componente padre!',
        }
      });



      // Obtiene el elemento div contenedor
      const contenedor = document.getElementById('componente-hijo-contenedor');

      // Agrega el componente hijo al div contenedor
      contenedor.appendChild(childComponent.$mount().$el);
    }

componente hijo 
//--------/
   props: ["message"],
  data() {
    return {
       },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.message)
    $(this.$refs.modalcallclient).modal('show');
  },

necesito que muestre los datos que se les va a enviar en el props pero no llega salen como indefinido

Tu app es puramente vue??? no tengo ni idea pq no te salen las props, nunca vi usar vue asi...

es un modal que simplemente me va funcionar para esa funcion en contreto me evito agregarlo directamente al template una vez se cierre el modal se destruye el componente

encontre la solucion el problema radicaba en como es el nombre de envio de props que no es realmente "props:" si no se envia como "propsData:"
childComponent() {
      const childComponent = new Vue({
        extends: CallClient,
        propsData: {
          message: '¡Hola desde el componente padre!',
        }
      });



      // Obtiene el elemento div contenedor
      const contenedor = document.getElementById('componente-hijo-contenedor');

      // Agrega el componente hijo al div contenedor
      contenedor.appendChild(childComponent.$mount().$el);
    }

